Does Ic reverse its current flow when BJT in common-emitter configuration goes from linear to saturated mode?
I don't understand how both junctions of BJT are forward biased in saturation mode. Does \$I_c\$ reverses? Does the saturation happen when \$V_{BE}\$ > \$V_{CE}\$ ?
Please explain the phenomenon using common emitter configuration.
P.S:

Consider a NPN transistor.
During saturation \$V_{CE}\$
is approx 0.2V
. Since \$V_{BE}\$
is always around 0.7V
for NPN. This means
$$VC=0.2V+VE$$$$VB=0.7V+VE.$$
Subtracting we get \$V_B−V_C=0.5V\$
, hence both junction are forward biased.

I get this. What I don't understand is since \$V_{B}\$ > \$V_{C}\$ now, why doesn't current flow from \$B\$ to \$C\$ now? If this happens how is there even something called saturation region. Why doesn't the whole processes that happened while in the working region stop?

Draw a B-C diode to see what is going on, for NPN the anode of a diode will be at the base terminal. As the collector current increases, we have a greater voltage drop across the RC resistor. Consequently, the Vc voltage drops as well. If Vc drops below 0.5V, the B-C diode will start to conduct. This additional current will flow through the B-C diode and back to the collector terminal and the GND. This current cannot flow upwards through the RC resistor because the ‘upper’ terminal of the RC resistor is at Vcc, and current can only flow from higher voltage to lower voltage

Jesse, have a look at the three models (all of them are identical, just phrased differently, math-wise) shown here. Take the case where saturation is taking place. Follow the math. See where it takes you. Those models are DC-complete. Both saturation and active mode are completely handled in the exact same models. No changes. Everything just works right. It's just that most of us break it into two parts and use two different ideas. The link there puts everything into a single, slightly more complex, idea.

@periblepsis I tried to read and understand that answer you put in your comment, but it is quite hard to understand since I am a beginner to electronics.

@JesseAlexanderjr. And that's why most of us break up the single larger all-in-one-place model into two parts. The transistor doesn't do that. It does physics without batting an eye. But we mortals prefer something simpler. Unfortunately, that comes at a price. Namely, your confusion about why current doesn't go where you think it should.

Buried in the middle of Edin Fific's  excellent and / but very long answer is this snippet which along with the accompanying diagram more or less answers your question all by itself. "It is almost like the base-emitter is a diode whose current controls the collector-emitter channel resistance, as below." - find this text and the related diagram in his answer and see what he's saying. Icb ADDS TO Ice when Vc < VB. There is no diode directly from  collector to emitter but functionally it is if there is one which is controlled by Ib.

@RussellMcMahon Thank you for your appreciation, means A LOT to me. I may edit it later on to be in order, I was updating it as it became more clear what Jesse wanted to understand. I actually answered it for myself as well, it was something I was wondering about for a long time as to how exactly this happens. I like your self-description on your "about" page. I think we would be good friends if we lived closer, and that we would probably even work on some projects together. I like to solve real-world problems and help the less fortunate, especially if it affects larger areas and populations.

EDIT #2: In your edited question, you have (rightfully so) shown your continued confusion, as your question wasn't really answered yet (I have added emphasis on the word "working"):

What I don't understand is since Vb>Vc now, why doesn't current flow from B  to C  now? If this happens how is there even something called saturation region. Why
doesn't the whole processes that happened while in the working region
stop?

FIRST, let me clear it up for you: BJT transistor NEVER STOPS WORKING as long as its base-emitter junction "diode" is forward-biased.
Your confusion stems partially from your incorrect view and from the slightly misleading naming of the transistor operating modes as active and saturation - a transistor is ACTIVE/WORKING (amplifying its base current) throughout both its LINEAR and SATURATION region!
In your mind, you may be thinking active and non-active. Our subconscious minds play such simple tricks on us sometimes, especially when our picture, knowledge or understanding of something is incomplete.
To help demonstrate my point, I have taken one of my examples from below to the most extreme case which never happens in reality but it helps you understand.
Let's assume the collector-emitter channel is so deep in saturation that it has ZERO resistance and the collector and emitter are practically shorted and at exactly the same, GROUND potential.
This would make the base-emitter junction diode and base-collector junction diode have EXACTLY the same voltages since both PN junctions will be connected in parallel.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Even in this unrealistic worst case scenario, the base-emitter diode conducts as much current as does the base-collector diode, in other words their currents are equal and the "amplification" of the transistor becomes 1, meaning no current amplification.
But this is practically impossible because the basic theory of "transistor-action" means that there has to be base-emitter current for the collector-emitter current to flow, this base-emitter current can't be greater than the collector-emitter current,  AND because the collector-emitter channel ALWAYS has some resistance.
Finally, a BJT is not just two diodes sandwiched back-to-back, but it has an additional collector-emitter channel represented as a resistor connected between collector and emitter, and its resistance depends upon the base current.
It is almost like the base-emitter is a diode whose current controls the collector-emitter channel resistance, as below.

simulate this circuit
The above schematic would be a more complete representation of a BJT.
For all of the above reasons, you will always have at least some voltage drop (at least a few mV) across the collector-emitter channel and the base-emitter voltage will never be less than the sum of the base-collector and collector-emitter voltages, even when the base-collector voltage is lower than the base-emitter voltage or even when the base-collector voltage is zero; its voltage relative to ground is still no less than the base-emitter voltage.
If the base-emitter voltage ever started becoming less than the Vbc+Vce, the base current would start going lower, which would start increasing the collector-emitter channel resistance, so this sort of a negative feedback prevents the transistor from ever being so saturated that it drops less voltage via the combination of BC and CE voltages than across the BE alone.

EDIT: Your question in the comment below has helped me figure out a better answer.
Let's start with an unsaturated transistor working in its linear region, as below.
The base-emitter junction is forward-biased with its typical forward diode voltage drop.
The base-collector junction is reverse biased.
Notice one thing here:
the Vbe voltage or the voltage across the base-emitter diode is equal to the sum of the Vbc and Vce voltages, in other words to the sum of the base-collector diode and collector-emitter channel voltage drops!
First an actual transistor schematic:

simulate this circuit
Now a diode representation "equivalent":

simulate this circuit

Now we look at the saturated transistor situation:
Again, first the transistor schematic:

simulate this circuit
And now the diode "equivalent":

simulate this circuit
Notice that we have exactly the same thing here with a saturated transistor as we did above with the non-saturated transistor:
the Vbe voltage or the voltage across the base-emitter diode is equal to the sum of the Vbc and Vce voltages, in other words to the sum of the base-collector diode and collector-emitter channel voltage drops!
So, apparently a bipolar junction transistor becomes saturated when its base-collector junction becomes forward biased and its voltage equals the base-emitter junction voltage.
Additionally, driving such a transistor deeper into saturation allows for a lower voltage drop across the collector-emitter channel, and this voltage adds to the base-collector diode voltage drop to equal the base-emitter voltage drop.
One more thing to notice is that the collector-emitter channel in all cases acts like a variable resistor whose resistance depends on the amount of the base current being injected into a part of the channel.
Just for an exercise and a further clarification, let's make the values of resistors such that the base-emitter diode and collector-emitter channel voltages are equal.
This is the point at which a transistor starts to enter into a saturation.
Notice that the voltage between base and collector or on the base-collector diode is actually ZERO!
What does this mean?
Does it mean that the base-collector diode/junction is shorted?
NO! Such thing can't happen inside a functional transistor, although it would seem to be the case based on zero voltage between base and collector.
What is ACTUALLY happening here is that the base current value has changed the collector-emitter resistance to the value which in that particular circuit (in combination with a particular load) develops a voltage drop equal to the base-emitter voltage at that moment.
The base and the collector electrodes are not shorted in this case, even if zero voltage between would make you believe they are.
This is another lesson to "take home": zero volts between two points or equal potential on two different points does not automatically mean they are shorted or connected to each other; it may mean that they are simply at the same potential at the moment.

simulate this circuit
Again, a diode "equivalent" schematic which should make what's going on a little more obvious:

simulate this circuit


OLD ANSWER BELOW:
No, the Ic does NOT reverse its direction. It still keeps flowing from collector to emitter (assuming positive/conventional current flow here).

simulate this circuit
As you can see in the above circuits, the one on the left is unsaturated, and the collector potential is above the base potential.
The one on the right is saturated, and the collector potential is lower than the base potential.
In both cases, the emitter current is equal to the sum of the base and collector currents.
Feel free to click on "simulate this circuit" to see it better and experiment with it.
And yes, the saturation happens when Vbe is larger than Vce, as the Vbe can't go below a certain voltage (typically around 0.6V for silicon transistor) if you want to keep the transistor switched ON, while the Vce saturation voltage can go close to 0V.
In that case, both PN junctions are forward biased.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Under some (unusual) conditions, current can indeed flow out of an NPN transistor's collector.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
However, under normal conditions V1 is much higher than the open-circuit saturation voltage of the transistor, so external current flows into the collector as usual in saturation.

Thank you for the answer. I actually came to this conclusion before posting it here. However, I can't get my mind off the contradiction of C being at a lower potential (voltage) than B, while being forward biased. and still not flowing current in the unusual B-C direction. Is there a better explanation we are missing, other than considering that the current flows this way because it cannot oppose the highest voltage in the circuit Vcc ?

Some current from the base flows internally between collector and emitter. When Vbe is ~0.7V then there's a good conductive path between C and E. Although with (say) 100mV Vce(sat) most of it  (like 90%) won't flow that way.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany I gave him a lengthy and graphic explanation about this. I would appreciate your opinion on it if you ever get the time and feel like reading it.

Or you can just plug the transistor "upside down" and have it still work at a lower saturation voltage and much lower (reverse) beta :) There was some Japanese low voltage switcher design for a mainframe/"big iron" computer that used power transistors that way as low-saturation switches, before mosfets became plentiful.

@EdinFifić  Looks good. The basic description of transistor operation is similar to AoE's transistor man but they omitted the second diode which you show.

Consider a NPN transistor.
During saturation \$V_\text{CE}\$ is approx \$0.2\text{V}\$. Since \$V_\text{BE}\$ is always around \$0.7\text{V}\$ for NPN. This means $$
\begin{align}
V_\text{C} = 0.2\text{V} + V_\text{E},\\ 
V_\text{B} = 0.7\text{V} + V_\text{E}.
\end{align}
$$
Subtracting we get \$V_\text{B} - V_\text{C} = 0.5\text{V}\$, hence both junction are forward biased.

I get this. but why doesn't current reverses and starts to flow other direction (B-C) since it is now forward biased. (Potential is higher in B than C)


What I don't understand is since  >  now, why doesn't current flow from  to  now?

Saturation in a BJT is truly something that challenges naive assumptions about electricity.
In a forward biased PN junction diode, we would expect to see free electrons move from the negative N region to the positive P region, and/or to see holes move from the positive P region to the negative N region. But in a saturated NPN transistor, where the base collector PN junction is forward biased, we see electrons flowing in the opposite direction, i.e. from the (more) positive P region to the (more) negative N region.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In an NPN transistor in saturation, the base more positive than the collector, yet electrons flow from the base into the collector, that is from the base region, not the base terminal. This challenges the naive intuition that electrons always flow from a more negative region to less negative (i.e. more positive region), except when there is an electromotive force, such as a battery, to make them move against the gradient.
Thinking in terms of conventional current, as opposed to electron flow, in a saturated NPN transistor, current flows from the less positive collector, through the more positive base.
To understand this, we must understand that conventional current does NOT always flow from more positive to less positive, and electrons do NOT always flow from more negative to less negative.
A gradient in the electric potential causes charges to accelerate. Electrons accelerate in the direction of a more positive potential. Interactions (called collisions) between electrons and their environment result in the acceleration being short lived, but after a collision an electron will begin to accelerate again. This process imparts a net velocity component to the average free electron. This is called drift.
The average drift velocity of electrons in a typical circuit is quite small in comparison to the individual velocities of electrons due to thermal motion. This is similar to how individual molecules in the air might be traveling at 500 m/s while a breeze might be blowing a mass of air at only a few cm/s. However, in the case of electrons, the difference in velocities is much more dramatic. For example, in copper at room temperature, the average speed of an individual electron due to thermal motion is about 100 km/s. On the other hand, the drift velocity might be only 1 mm/s!
So, an electric field causes electron drift velocity, but this drift is only a very small portion of the total motion of an individual electron.
There is another effect which causes net movement of charges, and that is diffusion. Because electrons are in motion, free electrons will tend to diffuse from a region of higher concentration to one of lower concentration. (Holes will do something similar).
In a saturated NPN transistor, the collector is only very lightly doped. So unless electrons are injected into the collector from the base, the concentration of free electrons will be very small. On the other hand, the emitter is much more heavily doped than the base, and so when the the base-emitter junction is forward biased, a high concentration of free electrons is injected into the base from the emitter. The higher concentration of free electrons in the base than in the collector means that free electrons will diffuse to the collector, even when the electric field would potentially cause them to drift in the opposite direction. As long as the external circuit continuously removes those electrons from the collector (which will happen as long as the collector is more positive than the emitter), if the base has a high concentration of free electrons, they will flow into the collector even though the base is more positive than the collector.
Thus we have electrons flowing from the more positive base to the less positive collector in a saturated NPN transistor!

Comment from @LvW (in chat)

Only now I have detected a severe error in the answer from @MathKeepsMeBusy.
He wrote (saturation case): " electrons are flowing..... and then from the more positive P region of the base to the less positive N region of the collector. They are flowing against the gradient of the electric potential."
This is, of course , wrong. For the B-C junction also applies the same rule as for the B-E juncton: Electrons move in a direction towards the more positive potential - that means: From C to B.

@LvW think about the situation again. In an NPN transistor in saturation, conventional current is flowing from collector to base. That is, from the collector region into the base region, not out through the base terminal. Physically electrons are flowing from base (region) to collector (region). But the base-collector junction is forward biased, That means the base region is more positive than the collector region. So electrons are flowing from the more positive base region to the more negative collector region. That is what is so counter-intuitive about charge flow in a saturated (NPN transistor).

This doesn't explain what happens in saturated state when base and collector is forward biased

@JesseAlexanderjr. The base-collector junction is forward biased when the bjt is in saturation. So everywhere that I refer to the transistor being in saturation, you can understand that to mean that the base-collector junction is forward biased.

@JesseAlexanderjr. I may not have explained myself sufficiently clearly in my answer, but I hope you will engage with it, because, imho, it is the only answer to actually address the question of why current is apparently flowing in "wrong" direction in the forward biased base-collector "diode". If there is something about my answer you don't understand, I hope you will question me.

I read your answer, and I feel like yours and Edins answers will answer my confusion. I still have a confusion which I think I should self-investigate using your answers. I might need a few days to process and understand this so for now I will give you an upvote because this provides the process in words, contrast to Edins answer

@Math Keeps me Busy - I must admit that I cannot follow your last comment. You write: "So electrons are flowing from the more positive base region to the more negative collector region". That means: The conventional current direction through the open B-C junction would be from C to B? So this portion of the total current through th base node would be opposite to the direction of the "normal" base current from B to E. Hence, the total base current in saturation would be smaller than in normal operation (Ib from B to E only) ?
This contradicts all measurements in saturation mode.

@LvW In a saturated NPN transistor, just like one in the forward active mode, conventional current flows from the collector through the base to the emitter. That is free electrons flow in the opposite direction, through the base to the collector. In forward active mode, the collector is more positive than base, so the electron flow matches naive intuition. In the saturated mode, the collector is more negative, but the electrons still flow through the base into the collector. It doesn't contradict measurements, check again. Look at the simulation in my answer.

@Math Keeps Me Busy - I think, we are discussing the saturation mode (in comparison to the "normal" mode. That means: We should concentrate on the main difference between both modes - that is the B-C junction and its influence on the BASE CURRENT. Hence, all my arguments were related to the base current and its two portions (B-E resp. B-C junction) only. Unfortunately you speak about "currents" only - and this was the reason for such a misunderstanding between us. You were (mainly) speaking of the "conventional" current - and you mean "collector current" or "emitter current". That`s all.

Continued/Conclusion:  I agree to all of your statements regarding the "conventional" currents Ic resp. Ie - and , I think, all of my statements regarding the current Ib are also correct. Just a misunderstanding....

When thinking about how transistors work internally, I tend to think, not in terms of conventional current, but in terms of current of whatever carrier type is the majority carrier in the emitter.    This current flows from the emitter pin into the emitter, and then into the base. Some then flows out of the base pin, but the majority flows on through the collector. For an NPN, that is electrons, so it flows opposite conventional current. But it more faithfully represents what is actually happening.

Because the B-C junction is forward biased, there is a component of current flowing (assuming an npn transistor) into the base and out of the collector, yes.
There is also a component flowing, in most applications, into the collector and out of the emitter.
The total current at the collector is the sum of these two components, which can be directed into or out of the collector, or even be zero if they balance exactly.
There's a component into the base and out the emitter as well, but this doesn't (directly, anyway) impact the collector current.

When both junctions are forward biased (as a result of a large Ic which causes a voltage drop across Rc large enough to make Vbe>Vce) the base curent Ib increases correspondingly due to an additional portion Ibc through the B-C junction.
Nevertheless, the classical equation Ie=Ic+Ib is still valid.
However, due to the additional base current Ibc the net collector current Ic (through the node C) is somewhat smaller as anticipted by the relation Ic=B*Ib.
Therefore, Ic does not "reverse" its direction but there is a small additional portion in opposite direction.
Comment (Edit): The collector current Ice will flow still in the "normal" direction from C to E (npn case) because there is still a driving voltage Vce>0. However, The current Ic through the node C is not identical to the (largest) portion of Ic (here called Ice) which arrives at the emitter node (Ice=Ic+Ibc).
Here are the equations:
Ie=Ib+Ic  with Ib=Ibc+Ibe and Ic=Ice-Ibc, which leads to
Ie=Ibe+Ice

Thanks for the answer. I am quite confused with the notation, as I'm a beginner. Does, for example, Ibc supposed to mean current flow from C to B and likewise? or is it B to C?

When the BC junction is forward biased due to Vb>Vc the current Ibc goes, of course, from B to C and, therefore, will be in opposite direction if compared with   the "normal" Ic direction (from C towards E).

Since "The collector current Ice will flow still in the "normal" direction from C to E" then, since all of the collector current flows through the base, the collector current flows from the collector to the base region (as distinguished from the base terminal). Since this is conventional current, the electrons are flowing from the base region to the collector. Why? Clearly the collector (NPN, saturation) is more negative than the base, so it repels electrons. The reason is that the base is teeming with electrons (injected by the emitter). They diffuse from high concentration to low.

It depends on the collector voltage.
If (assuming a grounded emitter) you take the collector voltage below ground, then current DOES flow out of the collector, sourced from the base, as the BC 'diode' is now forward biassed.
This allows you to use a BJT transistor as a shunt switch in bipolar analogue applications. It's not however a very good one. For low distortion, a shunt FET is a far better, that is a FET is a far more linear shunt switch.
I have used just such a bipolar shunt switch as a crude phase detector, for a lock-in amplifier type application.

Thank you for the answer. I am still confused and you'll understand why if I told you why I got this question. If I plotted a transfer characteristic graph to the above scenario, and if $I_C$ flows OUT of the COLLECTOR, SOURCED from BASE, shouldn't the graphs, now constant saturated $I_C$ be drawn on the negative side of the coordinate system. Also, I feel like it won't be a constant if that happens, because when you increase $I_B$, $I_C$ should also increase to match that, right?

Don't let the approximations about a BJT's behaviour in one region confuse you to its actual behaviour in other regions. Note that I_C is not constant in saturation (don't know where that wrong idea came from), beta is not constant, a BJT is not two diodes (though it sometimes behaves as if it is). BJT models are valid for the amplifiying region, as that's the important one. Draw graphs to represent the behaviour correctly, though sometimes datasheets invert a graph to save space. Get a BJT, ground C, pass 1 or 10 mA into B, then vary V_E while observing I_E and I_C.

I took a look at the characteristics graph again. and you are correct. $I_C$ is in mili ampere range and $I_B$ in micro ampere range. However, the curve in the saturated region of the characteristic graph appears to be flat. Does this flatness convey, 1) $I_C$ is constant in saturation despite $I_B$ change, or 2) $I_C$ still changes but now in microamperes which is so small to express in the graph

I_C is NOT constant in the saturation range. The whole definition of saturation is that I_C is governed by the external circuit, not by the transistor. If you're looking at a graph, it would be worth putting an image up of it - with appropriate attribution of course - to show the points you are questioning.

The phenomenon of saturation (without going into the physical-mathematical descriptions) in the common emitter configuration of a BJT is clear when the collector characteristic curves of the BJT and the static load line are drawn. The operating point Q must be chosen at the center of the linear region so as to have equal variations of the voltage Vce, i.e. increases and decreases. When the operating point Q moves on the load line in Q', following an increase in the base current, the transistor is on and is in saturation. By further increasing the base current, the operating point is in Q'' and the more the base current increases, the more the saturation increases. In any case moving Q in the linear region, the base-collector junction is reverse biased, while the base-emitter junction is forward biased. On the contrary in the saturation region both junctions are forward polarized See photo:


Quote: " In any case, the base-collector junction is reverse biased.." No - that is not correct. Definition of saturation: Base-collector junction is forward biased.

The graphs of the characteristic curves are obtained from my calculations in which something is missing since in proximity to the origin the curves should pass through zero.

@LvW Thanks, I agree. I corrected the previous answer.

@ Francesco M. - No, the characteristic curves do NOT go through the origin.

@LvW Yes right. I realize that this fact has its importance and that I have neglected on that occasion.
